# map dictionary of function names and arguments

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have to execute a large number of functions, with a variety of different arguments. How can I map a function over a dictionary of functions w/ lists of arguments

Rather than:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

np.mean(a)
np.quantile(a,q=0.5)
np.quantile(a,q=0.5)
```

Unpack and execute across all combinations in dictionary:

```
f_dict = { 'maximum':{} ,
          'quantile': [{'q':"0.5"},{'q':'0.95'}]}
```

Comment: You have a dictionary of `str` objects mapped to other `dict` and `list` objects.... no functions in your dict... did you *mean* to use functions in your dict? What is the point of this dict?

Comment: The answer below should give you the desired result, but unless you want to load the dictionary from like a config file or some external source I would advise you to stick to regular function calls for better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend using the **actual functions** as the keys for the dictionary. Also, I recommend formalizing the dictionary values to be a list of dictionaries.

If you did both of these changes, then you can use something like so:

```
f_dict = { np.mean:[{}] ,
          np.quantile: [{'q':0.25}, {'q':0.5}]}

print([func(a, **arg) for func, args in f_dict.items() for arg in args])
#[3.5, 2.25, 3.5]
```

Comment: I believe the OP wanted to create a structure where he/she can apply all the functions with arguments all at once. Like `map()` but with the additional, changeable arguments